# How to make this sieve function lazy?

Tags: clojure

Here is the code:

```
;; Helper function for marking mutiples of a number as 0
(defn mark 
  ([xs k m] (mark xs k m []))
  ([xs k m mark-vec] 
   (loop [[x & rest-xs] xs
          k k
          mark-vec mark-vec
          ]
     (cond 
       (and (nil? x) (nil? rest-xs)) mark-vec
       (= k m) (recur rest-xs 1       (conj mark-vec 0))
       :else   (recur rest-xs (inc k) (conj mark-vec x))
       ))))

;; Sieve of Eratosthenes
(defn sieve
  ([xs] (sieve xs []))
  ([xs sieve-res]
   (loop [[x & rest-xs] xs
          sieve-res sieve-res]
     (cond 
       (and (nil? x) (nil? rest-xs)) sieve-res
       (= x 0) (recur rest-xs sieve-res)
       :else   (recur (mark rest-xs 1 x) (conj sieve-res x))))))

(take 10 (sieve (range 2 100)))
```

I want to make it receive something like `(iterate inc 2)` and generate an infinite sequence of primes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29705514/2472391

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be to build a proper functional incremental sieve, such as those described in Melissa E. O'Neill's [The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf).

Christophe Grand published some really beautiful incremental sieve implementations [here](http://clj-me.cgrand.net/2009/07/30/everybody-loves-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes/).

Comment: Is the Christophe Grand  link dead? Can't open it from here.

Comment: Cached version: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http%3A%2F%2Fclj-me.cgrand.net%2F2009%2F07%2F30%2Feverybody-loves-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes%2F